# Blue line at the end of the screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a dashboard from flutter. in my code, I have used the **singlechildscroll view** and it's not working. and I'm getting a **blue line** at the end of the page before the bottom navigation bar. I think it's because the page is not scrollable. There's no error display in the console.  how do I correct this? appreciate your help on this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import '../constants/colors.dart';
    import '../widgets/bottomNavigation.dart';
    
    class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
    }
    
    class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Container(
                  width: 30,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/user.png',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(),
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                child: Text(
                  "Hi, NEO",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 30,
              // ),
    
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Your Leads",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height:30 ,
              ),
    
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
    
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
    
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
    
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
    
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.lightGreen,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
    
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container(child: BottomNavigation())),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

//bottomnavigation

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigation> createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
}

class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a background color defined in your MaterialApp or any other parent widget?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the updated code, both classes return a `Scaffold` with an `Appbar`. Thus, the blue box you see at the bottom is the Appbar of the class `_BottomNavigationState`.

Please refer to the code below for a correct implementation of a `BottomNavigationBar`.

**Explanation**

Generally, if one wants to encapsulate a `BottomNavigationBar` in its own `Widget`, this `Widget` needs to return a `BottomNavigationBar` in its `build()` method and **not** a `Scaffold`.

But usually, a `BottomNavigationBar` is used as shown below, without using an extra Widget.

**Code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}
 
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}
 
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'HOME PAGE',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'COURSE PAGE',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'CONTACT GFG',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
 
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('GeeksForGeeks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),

      // HERE ! bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigatioBar(...)

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            title: Text('Courses'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.contact_mail),
            title: Text('Mail'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Source**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bottomnavigationbar-widget-in-flutter/

Comment: I have added the bottom navigation code as well in the question. please kindly  check now

Answer (score 0):

Okay I try your code and this is the result, I dont have any blue line, In your case I think you can try 2 possible solutions.

[image]

First one is to wrap your column with a singleChildScrollView, but I think you´ll need 2 columns one for the singleChildScrollView and another for the bottomNavigationBar.
Something like this:

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            child: Text(
              "Hi, NEO",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                //fontFamily: "Dubai"
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // SizedBox(
          //   height: 30,
          // ),
            
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                child: Text(
                  "Your Leads",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height:30 ,
          ),
            
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            
              Container(
                height: 75,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            
              Container(
                height: 75,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
            
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            
              Container(
                height: 75,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            
              Container(
                height: 75,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
      Expanded(child: Container( BottomNavigation )),
    ],
  ),
```

The second one is that your BottomNavigation have the problem of the blue line, and I can't test it because I don't see your code.

Comment: I have added the bottom navigation code as well in the question. please kindly check now

Comment: It seems that the error comes from the way you have implemented your BottomNavigationBar, if you try on a larger device you will notice that the 'BottomNavigationBar Sample' message is even printed, Here a link for a correct implementation https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter/